# Looking for a common solid which is very soluble in water, insoluble in a volatile solvent, and doesn't corrode ferrous metals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solvents

I'm looking for a way to make a shiny object 'matte', but temporarily. I'd like to be able to spray on a coating which is a uniform colour and wash it off easily, even from small 'nooks and crannies' in the surface.

I've looked into chalk paint ( https://www.montana-cans.com/en/spray-cans/spray-paint/chalk-400ml/montana-chalk-400ml ) but these use suspensions of eg. Carbon black or Titanium Dioxide, which are insoluble in water and difficult to wash off.

I'm wondering if there is a readily available compound which forms a suspension in a volatile solvent (for when it's sprayed on), which is soluble in water (so it's easy to wash off) and doesn't corrode ferrous metals (because the object I'm trying to coat is made from chrome steel with small rust pits already).

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try a dye such as rhodamine 6G its highly soluble in water but sparingly soluble in acetone and probably less so in less polar solvents such as hexane etc.  Rhodamine is used to dye bait in fishing so its very cheap.